# email address on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, email

I have an application on `google app engine` like `abc.appspot.com` can I have an email address to send/receive emails like `admin@abc.appspot.com` kindly help me.

**Edit**
here is my `SendMail` class

```
public class SendMail {
  private static String fromAddress = "abc@gmail.com";

  private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SendMail.class.getCanonicalName());

  // Send the Mail
  public void send(String toAddress, String subject, String msgBody)
      throws IOException {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

    try {
      Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
      msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddress));
      InternetAddress to = new InternetAddress(toAddress);
      msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
      msg.setSubject(subject);
      msg.setText(msgBody);
      Transport.send(msg, new InternetAddress[] { to });

    } catch (AddressException addressException) {
      log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Address Exception , mail could not be sent", addressException);
    } catch (MessagingException messageException) {
      log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Messaging Exception , mail could not be sent", messageException);
    }
  }
}
```

So it sends an email regarding `abc@gmail.com` but I want that it should send from `email@abc.appspot.com`.

Answer (score 1):

You can only receive emails in the form of `@abc.appspotmail.com`. AFAIK there is no way to have `@abc.appspot.com` as receiving address.

If you wan to receive emails from your custom domain, e.g. `@abc.com`, than the only way is to  have external email service forward emails to your `@abc.appspotmail.com`. Most domain registrars offer free limited email service with forwarding (we use GoDaddy and get limited forwarding free).

Comment: want to create an email address like `email@myapp.appspot.com`. cant i create one ? if yes then from where ?

Comment: @PeterKnego setFrom() and email@myapp.appspot.com no?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail#Senders_and_Recipients

Comment: But its not telling me that from where to create an email address ?

Comment: You don't need to create it, you just use them as if they already exist.

Comment: Why don't you just change the fromAdress variable?

Comment: even if I change that `fromAddress` variable, but that address don't exist in real.

Comment: it does not need to! receiving email to that address is another story, here are docs for that: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/receiving